# Large .las file processing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, las, memory

I have a .las file that contains 100.000.000 points (2.6 Gb) and I process it by the custom QGIS plugin based on PDAL and GDAL. The problem is in processing large files as described in the previous sentence: the QGIS just shuts down without any error in the terminal. How to be in this situation? With the small files (560 Mb) everything works well.

Comment: You need to tile the las file into smaller, overlapping tiles.

Comment: Кроме разбиения этого .las файла на отдельные части вы также можете увеличить объём используемой памяти для QGIS, (https://okdk.ru/kak-vydelit-bolshe-operativnoj-pamyati-dlya-opredelennyh-prilozhenij-v-windows-10/) Ещё можно увеличить файл подкачки https://remontka.pro/fail-podkachki-windows/ (но не увеличивайте его слишком сильно, действуйте осторожно)

Comment: @KVO : English only please ...